# Why is my flutter BluetoothLE Advertiser not sending any packages? Everything seems fine but i cant detect the ad packets with my esp322

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, esp32

Here is my main.dart Code:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:beacon_broadcast/beacon_broadcast.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BeaconBroadcastPage(),
    );
  }
}

class BeaconBroadcastPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BeaconBroadcastPageState createState() => _BeaconBroadcastPageState();
}

class _BeaconBroadcastPageState extends State<BeaconBroadcastPage> {
  final BeaconBroadcast beaconBroadcast = BeaconBroadcast();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _requestPermissionsAndStartAdvertising();

    // Monitor advertising state
    beaconBroadcast.getAdvertisingStateChange().listen((isAdvertising) {
      if (isAdvertising) {
        // Beacon is currently advertising
        log('Beacon is advertising');
      } else {
        // Beacon is not advertising
        log('Beacon is not advertising');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _stopBeaconAdvertising();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _requestPermissionsAndStartAdvertising() async {
    PermissionStatus statusBluetooth = await Permission.bluetooth.status;
    if(statusBluetooth.isDenied){
      await Permission.bluetooth.request();
    }

    if (await Permission.bluetooth.status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      openAppSettings();
    }
    // Request Bluetooth permission
    PermissionStatus statusLocation = await Permission.location.request();
    if(statusLocation.isGranted){
      PermissionStatus statusBluetoothAdvertise= await Permission.bluetoothAdvertise.request();


      PermissionStatus statusBluetoothScan = await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();    // Request Location permission
      if (statusBluetoothAdvertise.isGranted && statusLocation.isGranted && statusBluetoothScan.isGranted && statusBluetooth.isGranted) {
        // Permissions granted, check transmission support
        BeaconStatus transmissionSupportStatus =
        await beaconBroadcast.checkTransmissionSupported();

        switch (transmissionSupportStatus) {
          case BeaconStatus.supported:
          // You're good to go, you can advertise as a beacon
            _startBeaconAdvertising();
            break;
          case BeaconStatus.notSupportedMinSdk:
          // Your Android system version is too low (min. is 21)
            log('Beacon transmission not supported: Android version is too low.');
            break;
          case BeaconStatus.notSupportedBle:
          // Your device doesn't support BLE
            log('Beacon transmission not supported: Device does not support BLE.');
            break;
          case BeaconStatus.notSupportedCannotGetAdvertiser:
          // Either your chipset or driver is incompatible
            log('Beacon transmission not supported: Chipset or driver issue.');
            break;
        }
      } else {
        // Handle permission denial or navigate to settings to enable permissions
        log('Permission denied for Bluetooth or Location');
      }
    }



  }

  void _startBeaconAdvertising() {
    beaconBroadcast
        .setUUID('39ED98FF-2900-441A-802F-9C398FC199D2')
        .setMajorId(1)
        .setMinorId(1)
        .start();
    log("Beacon advertising started");
  }

  void _stopBeaconAdvertising() {
    beaconBroadcast.stop();
    log("Beacon advertising stopped");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BLE Beacon App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Your phone is now a BLE beacon!',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _stopBeaconAdvertising,
              child: Text('Stop Advertising'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _requestPermissionsAndStartAdvertising,
              child: Text('Start Advertising'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Mainifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:label="finalbeacon"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tryed with this code to send bluetoothle packtes with an UUID and i wanted to detect those packets with my microcontroller. I can detect a lot of devices but nut the UUID of my phone why is that. I thougth maybe i dont have the rigth permissions or maybe my android version is the problem but i try it with different phones and different approaches but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried to search for your phone using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? You would need to install it on a different phone, but it would help to understand where the problem lies, either with your flutter application or with your esp32

Comment: Also, could you add the code used on your esp32? This might help to see whats going on